# ¿Cómo hacer que paren los hilos?

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo que hacer una carrera de 100 metros lisos. Tengo 8 atletas. Mi problema es que cuando ejecuto el proyecto, todo va bien pero no termina jamás la carrera no se donde tengo el fallo. Necesito que me saque el tiempo que en teoría debe ser entre 9 y 11 segundos.

Esta es la clase atleta:

```
   public class Atleta extends Thread {

    private int distancia;
    private String dorsal;
    private PistaCarrera pista;

    public Atleta(String dorsal) {
        distancia = 0;
        this.dorsal = dorsal;
    }

    public PistaCarrera getPista() {
        return pista;
    }

    public void setPista(PistaCarrera pista) {
        this.pista = pista;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
             int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - (10 + 1)) + (10));
            distancia += random;
            if (distancia > pista.getMeta()) {
                pista.cruzarMeta(this);
                }
            try {
                sleep(800);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Atleta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getDistanciaRecorrida() {
        return this.distancia;
    }

    public String getDorsal() {
        return dorsal;
    }

}
```

Esta la pista:

```
public class PistaCarrera {

    private Atleta a1;
    private Atleta a2;
    private Atleta a3;
    private Atleta a4;
    private Atleta a5;
    private Atleta a6;
    private Atleta a7;
    private Atleta a8;
    private boolean CruarMeta = false;
    private int meta;

    public PistaCarrera(int meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public void setAtletas(Atleta a1, Atleta a2, Atleta a3, Atleta a4, Atleta a5, Atleta a6, Atleta a7, Atleta a8) {
        a1.setPista(this);
        a2.setPista(this);
        a3.setPista(this);
        a4.setPista(this);
        a5.setPista(this);
        a6.setPista(this);
        a7.setPista(this);
        a8.setPista(this);
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
        this.a3 = a3;
        this.a4 = a4;
        this.a5 = a5;
        this.a6 = a6;
        this.a7 = a7;
        this.a8 = a8;
    }

    public int getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public boolean isCruarMeta() {
        return CruarMeta;
    }

    public void empezarCarrera() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Preparados");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("listos");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("ya");
            a1.start();
            a2.start();
            a3.start();
            a4.start();
            a5.start();
            a6.start();
            a7.start();
            a8.start();
            a1.join();
            a2.join();
            a3.join();
            a4.join();
            a5.join();
            a6.join();
            a7.join();
            a8.join();
            System.out.println("Carrera finalizada");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PistaCarrera.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void cruzarMeta(Atleta corredor) {
        while (corredor.getPista().isCruarMeta() == false) {
            CruarMeta = true;
            double tiempo = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            System.out.println("El dorsal [" + corredor.getDorsal() + "] tarda  " + tiempo + " segundos");
        }
    }
}
```

y el main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Atleta corredor1 = new Atleta("01");
        Atleta corredor2 = new Atleta("02");
        Atleta corredor3 = new Atleta("03");
        Atleta corredor4 = new Atleta("04");
        Atleta corredor5 = new Atleta("05");
        Atleta corredor6 = new Atleta("06");
        Atleta corredor7 = new Atleta("07");
        Atleta corredor8 = new Atleta("08");
        PistaCarrera pista = new PistaCarrera(100);
        pista.setAtletas(corredor1, corredor2, corredor3, corredor4, corredor5, corredor6, corredor7, corredor8);
        pista.empezarCarrera();

    }
```

Comment: A la clase atleta no le pasas la pista creada nunca y ahi estas calculando quien llega, sería mejor crear otra clase carrera donde pases al atleta y la pista y en ese clase haces el metodo en que calculas quien llega primero para no tener que pasarle a cada atleta una pista.

Comment: te cambio un poco el codigo porque si termina pero termina uno nada mas.Necesito que terminen todos y me den el tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Hice varios cambios, lo hice usando solo el join(), no sabria decir en especifico porque no te funciabana pero debe ser por el metodo synchorizada probablemente estuviese mal, tambien tenias las clases muy mezcladas trata de que cada clase se encargue de ella misma no de las demas.
El tiempo no esta en segundos porque van a tardar muy parecido pero siquieres en segundos puedes dividelo en 1000 como antes.

```
public class Atleta extends Thread {

    private int distancia;
    private String dorsal;
    private Pista pista;
    private boolean cruzo = false;
    private double tiempo;

    public Atleta(String dorsal) {
        distancia = 0;
        this.dorsal = dorsal;
    }

    public Pista getPista() {
        return pista;
    }

    public void setPista(Pista pista) {
        this.pista = pista;
    }



     @Override
        public void run() {
  long tiempo1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (!cruzo) {
                int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - (10 + 1)) + (10));
                distancia += random;
                if (distancia > pista.getMeta()) {
    //                pista.cruzarMeta(this);
                    long tiempo= System.currentTimeMillis()-tiempo1;                
                setTiempo(tiempo);
                    setTiempo(tiempo);
                    System.out.println("El dorsal [" + getDorsal() + "] tarda  " + tiempo + " segundos");
                    cruzo = true;

                }
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
    //                Logger.getLogger(Atleta.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }

        public int getDistanciaRecorrida() {
            return this.distancia;
        }

        public String getDorsal() {
            return dorsal;
        }

        public double getTiempo() {
            return tiempo;
        }

        public void setTiempo(double tiempo) {
            this.tiempo = tiempo;
        }



    }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Pista {
    private int meta;

    public Pista() {
    }

    public Pista(int meta) {
      this.meta = meta;
    }

    public int getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public class Carrera {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Atleta a1 = new Atleta("01");
        Atleta a2 = new Atleta("02");
        Atleta a3 = new Atleta("03");
        Atleta a4 = new Atleta("04");
        Atleta a5 = new Atleta("05");
        Atleta a6 = new Atleta("06");
        Atleta a7 = new Atleta("07");
        Atleta a8 = new Atleta("08");
        Pista pista = new Pista(500);
        a1.setPista(pista);
        a2.setPista(pista);
        a3.setPista(pista);
        a4.setPista(pista);
        a5.setPista(pista);
        a6.setPista(pista);
        a7.setPista(pista);
        a8.setPista(pista);

        try {
            System.out.println("Preparados");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("listos");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("ya");
            a1.start();
            a1.join();
            a2.start();
            a2.join();
            a3.start();
            a3.join();
            a4.start();
            a4.join();
            a5.start();
            a5.join();
            a6.start();
            a6.join();
            a7.start();
            a7.join();
            a8.start();
            a8.join();

            System.out.println("Carrera finalizada");

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Carrera.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

       ArrayList <Atleta> ganador= new ArrayList<>();
       ganador.add(a1);
       ganador.add(a2);
       ganador.add(a3);
       ganador.add(a4);
       ganador.add(a5);
       ganador.add(a6);
       ganador.add(a7);
       ganador.add(a8);
       ganadorCarrera(ganador);


    }

    public static void ganadorCarrera(ArrayList <Atleta>competidores){
        double ganador = competidores.get(0).getTiempo();
        String dorsal = competidores.get(0).getDorsal();
        for (int i = 0; i < competidores.size(); i++) {
            if (competidores.get(i).getTiempo()<ganador) {
                ganador=competidores.get(i).getTiempo();
                dorsal=competidores.get(i).getDorsal();

            }
        }
        System.out.println("El ganador es " + dorsal + "con " + ganador);

    }

}
```